# Android finish a certain activity instance, regardless if its single or multiple

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-activity

I am wondering if there is a good approach to finishing an activity with multiple instance. I made that behave w/ multiple instance (default) launchMode on purpose.

For example I got Activity A and I go to Activity B. There is a Chance for me to do these scenarios:

- Scenario 1 = A > B > B > C and I want to destroy all instances of B only
- Scenario 2 = A > B > B > C and follow the current back stack no problem

But for Scenario 1, I need to retain the state of A (In Activity A this is the selected Tab state scrolled in this item etc etc.)

**What have I tried so far:**

- I tried modifying launchMode in manifest, its not what I need
- Tried using finishAffinity() but it destroys all running activities
- Tried using Intent with CLEAR_TOP or NEW_TASK but it resets my Activity A state
- finishActivity(requestCode)
- Browsed some previous questions here in StackOverflow regarding this but no luck for me.

*The scenarios are solved using if else statement and I managed to solve the problem just by calling finish() twice but is there any other way around it? Its kinda messy having to call finish() twice along with a boolean checker.*